# Self-closing tag syntax error in HTML documents

Tags: html, validation, tags

Using the [W3c.org HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), today I started receiving a new error indicating an issue with ***all*** self-closing HTML tags.  **The error is**:

> Warning: Self-closing tag syntax in text/html documents is widely
> discouraged; it’s unnecessary and interacts badly with other HTML
> features (e.g., unquoted attribute values). If you’re using a tool
> that injects self-closing tag syntax into all void elements, without
> any option to prevent it from doing so, then consider switching to a
> different tool.

One of the examples of problematic HTML was:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Is this a recent change? What is the best practice for closing tags in light of this change?

Comment: Self-closing tags are part of the HTML5 syntax. Was XHTML a pain? Yes. Is it good that self-closing tags are optional in HTML5? Yes. Should they be entirely banned? I don't think so. They make HTML code much more readable to novice users.

Answer (score 3):

> The error is

…a **warning**, not an error.

> Is this a recent change?

It's not a warning I've come across before, and is [under active development](https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/9b46b7313f55451737040136a00a5e71008865b5) with [an open issue relating to it](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/1429) so it is probably pretty new.

> What is the best practice for closing tags in light of this change?

A matter of opinion. The warning gives the validator authors' opinion along with their justification.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening to me this morning too. However, the solution is simple.
All you have to do is delete **/** from your code.
For example, Instead of

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Write this

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
```

To fix this easily in your document, select **/>** and press **Crtl+D** .

This will select all the tags which causes the warning. You can easily delete **/** in that way.

Comment: This did NOT work. I tried that but the back slashes were added back in with I check the HTML validator page again.

Comment: @SusanFarrar u sure about that? I already fixed that using that way yesterday.

Comment: @SusanFarrar You are probably using some tool that process HTML, and that is adding slashes to your self-closing tags. W3C's Markup Validation Service doesn't modify the code you give it as an input, it only analyze its structure, looking for anything out of specification.

Comment: This answer does not really address the question (when did this change, and what is the new best practice), and the instructions assume the use of a particular editor and OS.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the warning is a false positive.

It should only apply if the last attribute isn't enclosed in quotes.

This is what W3c refers to: Consider the following two cases for marking up an img element for an image located at http://www.example.com/logo.svg:

- img element without trailing slash:

  `<img alt=SVG src=http://www.example.com/logo.svg>`
- img element with trailing slash:

  `<img alt=SVG src=http://www.example.com/logo.svg/>`

In the first case (without the trailing slash), the value of the src attribute in the DOM becomes http://www.example.com/logo.svg, as expected.

However, in the second case (with the trailing slash), the value of the src attribute in the DOM unexpectedly becomes http://www.example.com/logo.svg/ — which breaks display of the image.

Example:

```html
<ul>
<li>img element with trailing slash:
<img alt=SVG src=https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg/>
<li>img element without trailing slash:
<img alt=SVG src=https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg>
</ul>
```

[Source](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values)

Comment: Although I see the logic of your answer, the HTML validator is displaying a warning on ALL self-closing tags.