# Have received a warning message when using w3.org html checker. Have removed / but keeps appearing after saving file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I was using the W3.org HTML checker and received this warning message.
*Self-closing tag syntax in text/html documents is widely discouraged; it’s unnecessary and interacts badly with other HTML features (e.g., unquoted attribute values). If you’re using a tool that injects self-closing tag syntax into all void elements, without any option to prevent it from doing so, then consider switching to a different tool.

From line 4, column 5; to line 4, column 28

`<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

I removed the / but every time I save the file again the / appears in the same line again. Using vscode by the way. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this behavior occur with other tags (such as `<img>`, `<br>`, or other `<meta>` tags in your code)? If so, this could be an issue with Prettier auto-formatting your code. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691612/) to find steps to prevent Prettier from automatically adding slashes to your tags.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999326/11107541